# how to change text of label in datalist at page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, label, datalist, pageload

```
<asp:datalist ID="Datalist1" runat="server" 
                      Width="500px" >
                    <ItemTemplate>


<asp:Button ID="btnviewfullprofile" runat="server"   Text="View Full Profile" ToolTip="Click for Full Profile of User"  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Uid")%>'  CommandName="fullprofile" />



 <asp:Button ID="sendinterest" runat="server" Text="Send Interest"  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Uid")%>'  CommandName="sendinterest" />

 <asp:Label ID="lblstatus" runat="server" Visible="False"     ></asp:Label>                 


</ItemTemplate>
   </asp:datalist>
```

text of label will change according to the value of status stored in database.

code for button

```
if (e.CommandName == "fullprofile")
    {
        int Id = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        Response.Redirect("~/FullProfile.aspx?Id=" + Id);


 `enter code here`   }
```

but what should i write for label so that text of label should change itself based on value of status stored in database

Comment: how come 'enter code here' after response.redirect

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need to change the HTML to something like:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblstatus" runat="server" Visible="False" 
   Text='<%# Eval("DatabaseField") %>' />
```

You are already using this for the `CommandArgument` of the button. Obviously you need to replace 'DatabaseField' with the name of the field that you want to show as text. ASP.net will fill the `Text` attribute with the correct value from your datasource.

Comment: I know, but the text of the label comes from the datasource right? It is in the same row as the `Uid` field that you are already using, if I guessed correctly. If not, you really need to clarify your question.

Comment: yes , may i chat/email u , my email is aryarajat@gmail.com may i know ur ?

Comment: i am using this to send friend request to users.datalist contain some field like , name , age , gender that will filled from table USER , and Label will show the status of friend request  that is stored in other table "friends" . Label will show text based on column [Status] value like ( if status 1 then friend request pending) . so i want to use label to show status.

Answer (score 0):

as you are binding commandargument of the button from database, same way you can bind the text property of the label

```
<asp:Label ID="lblstatus" runat="server" Visible="False" Text= '<%#Eval("textfield")%>'    ></asp:Label>
```

If you need more advance control then you need to set them when items are getting bound see here fore details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemdatabound.aspx

Comment: but please tell me how to use this in C# ,